# Cast object, de-serialized as an interface, back to its original type

Tags: c#, interface, casting, json.net

```
namespace Animals
{
    interface IAnimal
    {
        string MakeNoise();
    }

    class Dog : IAnimal
    {
        public string MakeNoise()
        {
            return "Woof";
        }
    }

    class Cat : IAnimal
    {
        public string MakeNoise()
        {
            return "Miauw";
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog dog1 = new Dog();
            dog1.Name = "Fikkie";

            var jsonAnimal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dog1);
            IAnimal animal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IAnimal>(jsonAnimal) as IAnimal;
            animal.MakeNoise();
        }
    }
}
```

I am serializing and storing several Dog and Cat classes of which all implement the IAnimal interface, which contain all the properties and methods I need. When de-serializing I need to get them to have the IAnmial interface again.

The DeserializeObject now throws an error: 'Could not create an instance of type Animals.IAnimal. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

**I cannot change the Newtonsoft execution as this is happening in a class that's not accessible**, so unfortunately the TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All is not possible. The method does expect a type, so it seems the exact implementation as I have in this example.

Comment: You shouldn't even use IAnimal in this situation. You should have a Generic Animal class with common properties like name and type. Then you extend that into Dog or Cat. When you deserialize, you can correctly infer the types.

Comment: This is just an example. the Interface has many methods that are all uniquely implemented in the classes that implement the interface. I just need the interface back so I can call the methods in my code. Just changed the example a bit

Comment: You can't instantiate interfaces. Instead, with a Generic Animal class, you should be able to cast them to correct type to use those class methods like `Animal someAnimal ...; if (someAnimal.type == "Dog") return (Dog)someAnimal;`

Comment: The interface is just a bunch of methods, and all classes have their own unique implementation for it. I don't see how a generic class would help here

Comment: SILENT - that won’t work because the concrete type of the *created instance* is Animal, not Dog. Attempting to cast to a Dog will fail with an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @user2864740 You're right. Still in JavaScript mindset.

Comment: @Bastiaan You mentioned in another comment that you don't have access to the JSONConvert. Do you still have access to serialized JSON that is given to JSONConvert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported error is because *interfaces cannot be instantiated* and, by default, Json.NET has no rules/knowledge of how to map suitable concrete types from arbitrary interfaces. However, *simply using a non-abstract base class that, unlike an interface, can be instantiated is insufficient*. If this were done an instance of the base type would be created on deserialization: this is incorrect as the original class type is expected to be instantiated.

For a round-trip process to work through a polymorphic base type, such as IAnimal (or an Animal base class), enough information about the *concrete type* needs to be saved in the JSON. On deserialization this information is used to create an instance of the *original concrete type*.

Given the issue/approach identified above, and stated restrictions, **this task can be solved using a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) with a [JsonConverterAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) on the IAnimal interface<sup>+</sup>**.

- The converter is *responsible to store metadata and create instances of the original concrete type*.

  In the provided implementation this uses Json.NET’s built-in support through  [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) which “..include[s] type information when serializing JSON and read[s] type information so that the [original] types are created when deserializing JSON.”
- The attribute *allows the converter to be used without explicitly adding it to the serialization or deserialization call-sites*.

<sup>+</sup>This approach will work if *either* IAnimal has the attribute added, or a serializable wrapper type has the converter attribute added to an IAnimal property. As a potential downside, *this approach requires implementation contract guarantees* – ie. that Json.NET is used.

---

This code runs in LINQPad as a Program, when referencing Json.NET version 12 and adding `Newtonsoft.Json` as an additional namespace.

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json

public void Main() {
    var dog = new Dog();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dog);
    // json -> {"$type":"UserQuery+Dog, query_mtutnt"}
    var anAnimal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IAnimal>(json);
    Console.WriteLine($"{anAnimal.GetType().Name} says {anAnimal.Noise}!");
    // -> Dog says Woof!
}

[JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(AnimalConverter))]
public interface IAnimal
{
    [JsonIgnore] // don’t save value in JSON
    string Noise { get; }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Noise => "Woof";
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Noise => "Meow";
}

internal sealed class AnimalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    // Have to prevent the inner serialization from infinite recursion as
    // this code is leveraging the built-in TypeNameHandling support.
    // This approach will need updates if there are nested IAnimal usages.
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static bool TS_Converting;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var mySerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });

        try
        {
            TS_Converting = true;
            mySerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
        finally
        {
            TS_Converting = false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var mySerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });

        return mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return !TS_Converting; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IAnimal).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

As seen in the resulting JSON, shown as `{"$type":"UserQuery+Dog, query_mtutnt"}`, the generalized approach of encoding the full type name can be problematic if the type’s namespace or assembly is changed. (Trivially, the JSON is not transferable between LINQPad runs due to the changing randomized assembly name.)

If this were my project, I might write the converter to to use a JSON structure such as `["dog", {"age": 2}]` and use reflection/attributes to map "dog" to Dog (a known subtype of IAnimal). However, a ‘better’ domain encoding falls outside of the original question and such can be explored in a refined follow-up as warranted.

On a final note, when the library cannot be guaranteed to use Json.NET and it “must” be used to serialize/deserialize, it may still be possible to manually map-to/from a Object-Graph representation (eg. dictionaries, arrays, and primitives) that can be round-tripped though the library. This still involves encoding the concrete type on map-to so that it can used to create the correct instance on map-from.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, that's really helpful, have gone with this approach

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want dynamic way then you have to do following thing in serialization and deserialization process.

```
var jsonAnimal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dog1, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });

IAnimal animal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonAnimal, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            }) as IAnimal;
```

Comment: That's the problem I am having, I cannot change the JsonConvert methods, as they are happening in a separate class I cannot change..